# Tableview cell data changed on API callback after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, block, objective-c-blocks

My application list an array of feeds. Feeds are displayed in a tableview. Each cell has a likebutton and a feed data object. When the likebutton is clicked, an API call will happen and it is written inside the table cell subclass. On success of the API call I need to update the likebutton image and feed data object. But if I scroll the tableview after starting the API call and before receiving Onsuccess, the data object and likebutton I refer in the Onsuccess method will have a different index(due to cell reuse). How can I refer the data object when the API call was started? My code is given below.

```
#import "FeedCell.h"
- (IBAction)likeAction:(id)sender
{
 [APIManager unlikeORunlikePost:self.feedObject.entityID withSuccess:^(id response)
  {
  //Here I want to get the 'self.feedObject' which was passed to the API manager 
  //If I try to get 'self.feedObject' , that object will be different from what I passed initially if the tableview is scrolled before entering this success block
  } 
  andFailure:^(NSString *error)  
  {
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

weakly capture the feed object in the block and compare it to the cells current feed object, if they are the same then the cell hasn't been reused.

Answer (score 3):

The block is only capturing `self`, which is the cell, and as you've found this is changed if you have scrolled the table and the cell is reused.

Capture the specific data object instead:

```
- (IBAction)likeAction:(id)sender
{
 FeedObject *feedObject = self.feedObject;
 [APIManager unlikeORunlikePost:feedObject.entityID withSuccess:^(id response)
  {
      [feedObject doSomething]; // This will now be the original object
  //Here I want to get the 'self.feedObject' which was passed to the API manager 
  //If I try to get 'self.feedObject' , that object will be different from what I passed initially if the tableview is scrolled before entering this success block
  } 
  andFailure:^(NSString *error)  
  {
 }];
}
```

However:

- Should your cell be doing much more after this completion call? Isn't it the responsibility of a different object?
- Returning the affected object in the completion block would be neater

Comment: This also a great solution. Thanks. I've already accepted the above answer. So I have upvoted this answer.